# How to change contents of a div based on timer

Tags: jquery

Is there any way in jquery to change the contents of a div based on timer.

Assume i have module to give "tips". The contents of the tips should change every 5 seconds.

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Make an array of tips. Then make a `interval` of 5 seconds that change the div's content. I assume you want random tips.

**[See this example on jsFiddle.](http://www.jsfiddle.net/brunolm/CDzXQ/)**

```
var tips = [
    "Tip 01",
    "Tip 02",
    "Tip 03",
    "Tip 04",
    "Tip 05",
    "Tip 06",
    "Tip 07",
    "Tip 08",
    "Tip 09"
];

// get a random index, get the value from array and
// change the div content
setInterval(function() {
    var i = Math.round((Math.random()) * tips.length);
    if (i == tips.length) --i;
    $("#tip").html(tips[i]);
}, 5 * 1000);
```

See:

- [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setInterval)
- [jQuery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)
- [jQuery html](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

Comment: +1 Now, two years on, why did you decide to use the expression `5 * 1000` instead of just `5000`, illustration?

Comment: @msanford ^I think it was just for demonstrating 5 multiplied by 1000 milliseconds. :)

Answer (score 7):

javascript has a method [called `.setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setInterval), which will run code every n milliseconds.

```
var $div = $('#myDiv');

var timer = setInterval( function() {
    $div.html( newContent ); // which would reference some dynamic content 
}, 5000);
```

By storing the return value of `.setInterval()` in a variable, you can stop the interval later by [using `.clearInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.clearInterval).

```
clearInterval( timer );
```

Comment: this site is really awesome, whenever i stuck in development , if i post  doubt i am getting answer with in fraction of seconds.I started UI development very recently like 8 months back only.