# How to change contents of a div (NOT in random)

Tags: javascript, html

How to change contents of a div based on timer
[How to change contents of a div based on timer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4005389/how-to-change-contents-of-a-div-based-on-timer)

nice script! 
is it possible to have "Tip01", "Tip02", "Tip03", and so on, till "Tip09", and after starting again from "Tip01", and not in a random one? thanks.

Comment: Please give us your effort, your code please

Answer (score 2):

You can remove the random part of that code and reset the value of `i` to `0` when it reaches to the end of the array:

```js
var tips = [
    "Tip 01",
    "Tip 02",
    "Tip 03",
    "Tip 04",
    "Tip 05",
    "Tip 06",
    "Tip 07",
    "Tip 08",
    "Tip 09",
    ];
    
var i = 0;    
setInterval(function() {
    $("#tip").html(tips[i]);
    i++ ;
    if(i == tips.length){
     i = 0;
    }
}, 500);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tip"></div>
```

Comment: why add jquery for single script when the question tags do not even include jquery?

Comment: Check the JSfiddle link OP has attached. It contains JQuery there. That could be a small snippet of bigger code. @MateuszJuruś

Comment: @MateuszJuruś that's fine mate

Answer (score 1):

```js
const tips = [
  "Tip 01",
  "Tip 02",
  "Tip 03",
  "Tip 04",
  "Tip 05",
  "Tip 06",
  "Tip 07",
  "Tip 08",
  "Tip 09",
];
let i = 0;
setInterval(function() {
  document.querySelector('#tip').textContent = tips[i];
  i++;
  if (i === tips.length) i = 0;
}, 300);
```

```html
<div id="tip"></div>
```